# Filtrar por fechas

Tags: sql

Necesito poder realizar una consulta que me muestre los productos que no se vendieron en un rango de fechas.

La Base de Datos :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla:

```
select p.ProductID,p.ProductName,p.CategoryID,o.OrderDate,DAY(o.OrderDate) as 'Dia Vendido',MONTH(o.OrderDate) as 'Mes Vendido',YEAR(o.OrderDate) as 'Año Vendido'
from Products p join [Order Details] od on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
join Orders o on o.OrderID=od.OrderID
where p.Discontinued = 0 
and p.CategoryID = 8 
and YEAR(o.OrderDate)=1996 
and (o.OrderDate not between '1996-08-01' and '1996-08-15')
```

Esta mal, porque debería de salir así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @Jimmy deberías poner la estructura de tu tabla y que es lo que has intentado, además te invito a que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) de SO para ver cómo funciona el sitio y ver la forma de cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta no sea cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Creo que te falta hacer un join con Categories

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza el [BETWEEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

algo como `NOT BETWEEN FECHA_INICIO AND FECHA_FIN` deberia bastarte.

Ejemplo:

```
Select * from persona where persona.fecha_nacimiento not between '2017-06-06' and '2017-06-08';
```

Comment: Gracias por responder @Galbi,tengo una consulta, en si lo que tengo que hacer es sacar los productos que no se han vendido entre el 1° y el 15 de Agosto de 1996, es de la tabla de northwind.  La tabla esta aca : https://camo.githubusercontent.com/ad43beb5737bc55c90d3b6dd120fcfe1316238ea/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f493236773954392e706e67

Comment: estuve haciendo esto pero no esta bien             select p.ProductID,p.ProductName,p.CategoryID,DAY(o.OrderDate) as 'Dia Vendido',MONTH(o.OrderDate) as 'Mes Vendido',YEAR(o.OrderDate) as 'Año Vendido'
from Products p join [Order Details] od on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
    join Orders o on o.OrderID=od.OrderID
where p.Discontinued = 0 and p.CategoryID = 8 and YEAR(o.OrderDate)=1996 and o.OrderDate not between '1996-08-01' and '1996-08-15'   `

Comment: A ver, lo primero, edita la pregunta. Pon la estructura de tu tabla, la consulta que estas haciendo formateada (porque me es complicadisimo leerla) y pon tambien el error que da o por qué no es correcto el resultado q obtienes

Answer (score 1):

Yo probaría así:

```
select p.ProductID,p.ProductName,p.CategoryID,o.OrderDate,DAY(o.OrderDate) as 'Dia Vendido',
MONTH(o.OrderDate) as 'Mes Vendido',YEAR(o.OrderDate) as 'Año Vendido'
from Products p join [Order Details] od on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
join Orders o on o.OrderID=od.OrderID
where p.Discontinued = 0 and p.CategoryID = 8 and 
o.OrderDate > '1996-01-01 00:00:00' and 
o.OrderDate < '1996-08-01 00:00:00' and 
o.OrderDate > '1996-08-15 0:00:00'
```

De todas maneras indica que fallo te da con tu consulta. Además te va a mostrar mas cosas que el ID, nombre y categoría, le has puesto más cosas en el select, si sólo quieres que te muestre Id, nombre y categoría ponle:

```
select p.ProductID,p.ProductName,p.CategoryID from ...
```